# How to set output log file name and path in Log4j?

Tags: android, log4j, android-sdcard

I am using Log4j API for maintaining logs in my Android Application. I am new to Android. I have Downloaded .JAR file regarding this. Now I want to store the log file on to SD Card. So where should I write output file name & its path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add appender ( where to append the log.. to a file or standard output etc )
In the configuration xml file given  [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Examplelog4jConfigurationFile.htm) ,your interest lies here

```
#define the appender named
FILE log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${user.home}/log.out
```

Comment: what is the value if ${user.home} , how can I set the value for it ?

Comment: you can ignore this and use "log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out" .This should create the file "log.out" in your application directory.

Comment: ya that I know , but I want to create file in SD Card Folder then ?

Comment: then you can try absolute path (referring to your desired folder).

Comment: will try & tell you if i will face any problem, by the way thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Log4j but, simple description of file writing on Android is like that:

first, declare permission in Manifest to write external storage :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then, in your code:

```
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + [Your filename];
```

Now You can write whatever in this file.

Comment: I know this too. but this is not what I required.